# Is the answer to this equation non-real or no-answer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, quadratic-forms

[image]

The equation is 0 = $25x^2$ - 30x + 58.

A = 25
, B = 30,
C = 58

Using the quadratic formula (as shown in the picture) I get
$\dfrac{{900\pm\sqrt{(-4900)}}}{ {50}} $.
When I put it in the calculator (either the + or -, not both at the same time) I get "Non-Real Error".  Is the answer not real?

Comment: It's not real; it's [imaginary](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/imaginary-numbers.html).

Comment: @JamesA It is not imaginary either. It is complex with a non-zero imaginary component.

Comment: @Deepak Whoops, yeh you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this equation is imaginary solutions or complex solution. To check it, use the formula $b^2-4ac$.

If $b^2-4ac$ is more than 0, then it has different real solution. For instance, x = 2 and x = 3.

If $b^2-4ac$ is equal to 0, then it has same real solution. For instance, x = 3 and x = 3.

If $b^2-4ac$ is less than 0, then it has complex solution. For instance, $x = 2 + 3i$ and $x = 2 - 3i$ where i is referring to imaginary number or $\sqrt{-1}$

In this case, a = 25, b = -30 and c = 58. By using the formula:
$$b^2-4ac=(-30)^2-4(25)(58)$$
$$b^2-4ac=900-5800$$
$$b^2-4ac=-4900 < 0$$

Hence it has complex solution or no real solution (no solution).

So, to solve it, just use Quadratic Formula:
$$x=\frac{b \pm{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}}{2a}$$
$$x=\frac{30 \pm{\sqrt{-4900}}}{50}$$
$$x=\frac{30 \pm{\sqrt{4900}i}}{50}$$
$$x=\frac{30 \pm{70i}}{50}$$
$$x=\frac{3 \pm{7i}}{5}$$
$$x=\frac{3+{7i}}{5},\frac{3-{7i}}{5}$$

Comment: I didn't realize you could divide the 70i by ten as well. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome.